# Scala: how to print inside a class using type parameterization

Tags: scala, types

I have an example code like this:

```
trait X{
  val a=1;
  val b=2;
}

case class Y(override val a:Int, override val b:Int) extends X{
  def sum(c:Int)=a+b+c
}

case class Z(override val a:Int, override val b:Int) extends X{
  def sum(c:Int)=a+b+c+10
}



object Test{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val z = Z(1, 2)
    val y = Y(3, 4)
    println (y.sum(5))
    MyTest[Z].myprint(z) //error here
  }
}

class MyTest[A] {
  def myPrint(z: A): Unit =
    if (z.isInstanceOf[A]) {
      val c = z.asInstanceOf[A]
      println(c.sum(4)) //error here
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a parameterized class MyTest with a function that will print the `sum` function of the class passed as parameter. I am getting two errors:

1. Can not resolve the symbol MyTest
2. I can not write `c.sum()`, because obviously the compiler has no information about what kind of class can be passed in A.

Note that if I put the method myPrint inside Test, which is a better design anyway, I still have the second problem.

What can be a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do

```
MyTest[Z].myprint(z)
```

as it is a class, you have to instantiate it first

```
val test = new MyTest[Z]
test.myprint(z)
```

by the way notice that you declared `myPrint` and you use `myprint` that is a different identifier...

or you could create an `object` with generic method

```
object MyTest {
  def myPrint[A](z: A): Unit = ???
}
```

About the other problem if you want to call `sum` tell compiler that myPrint takes an argument of type that has this method. You can for example put it in your trait

```
trait X {
  val a = 1
  val b = 2

  def sum(c: Int): Int
}
```

and implement it in subclasses

then you can declare it as

```
def myPrint(x: X): Unit =
  println(x.sum(4))
}
```

I put there `4` as argument as I have no idea what you really want to acomplish as your code does not pass any argument to function that you declared to take one `Int`

Another way of declaring the type (instead of adding `sum` to your `X` trait is to create another trait

```
trait Summable {
  def sum(c: Int): Int
}
```

and make your classes implement it

```
case class Y(override val a:Int, override val b:Int) extends X with Summable
```

and then `myPrint` would need to accept `Summable` instead of `X`

finally you can use structural typing and declare `myPrint` as follows

```
def myPrint(x: { def sum(a: Int): Int }): Unit =
  println(x.sum(4))
}
```

Comment: Am I not right about other things? You need more explanation or maybe I got your problem wrong?

Comment: No, no, you are right. I am just taking some time to test things :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Structural Types](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#structural) along side with [Bounds](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html), that basically defines which methods or attributes the given type should have in order to be used with your class. It's a feature very similar to duck type of dynamic languages.

That way your class definition can be rewrite as the following:

```
class MyTest[A <: { def sum(i: Int): Int }]
```

Since your `sum` methods receive an argument the invocation inside `myPrint` should pass it too. Fixing that, a working version of your code is:

```
trait X {
  val a = 1;
  val b = 2;
}

case class Y(override val a: Int, override val b: Int) extends X {
  def sum(c: Int) = a + b + c
}

case class Z(override val a: Int, override val b: Int) extends X {
  def sum(c: Int) = a + b + c + 10
}

class MyTest[A <: { def sum(i: Int): Int }] {
  def myPrint(z: A): Unit =
    println(z.sum(0)) // I added a zero just to fix the example
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val z = Z(1, 2)
    val y = Y(3, 4)
    println(y.sum(5))
    new MyTest[Z]().myPrint(z) //error here
  }
}
```